# Equivalence of two notions of 'separable morphism'

Tags: category-theory

Consider a family fibration $\Pi_0:\mathsf{Fam}(\mathsf A)\longrightarrow \mathsf{Set}$ and consider its right adjoint $H$ given by taking copowers of a terminal object. Let $\eta:1\Rightarrow H\Pi_0$ be the unit of this adjunction.

**Definition 1.** Say an arrow $\alpha:A\to B$ is a trivial covering if its naturality square is a pullback.

**Definition 2a.** Say an arrow $\alpha:A\to B$ is separable if its diagonal is a trivial covering.

**Definition 2b.** Say an arrow $\alpha:A\to B$ is separable if its diagonal is a coproduct injection.

> Why are definitions (2a) and (2b) equivalent?

It seems to me that $\alpha:A\to B$ being a trivial covering is equivalent to being a coproduct of coproducts of the identity over each connected component of $B$. Hence (2a) means $A$ itself is a coproduct of $A\times_B A$'s. On the other hand, (2b) says $A$ is part of a coproduct decomposition of $A\times _BA$. Already for $\alpha =1_A$ this doesn't make sense to me...

Equivalence of the definitions is claimed in the paper *Strongly separable morphisms in general categories* by Janelidze and Tholen, in example 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a function $f:I\to J$ and a $J$-indexed family $B=(B_j)_{j\in J}$ in $\mathsf{Fam}(\mathsf A)$, the pullback of $H(f)$ along $\eta_B$ is given by
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}(B_{f(i)})_{i\in I}@>>> (1)_{i\in I} \\ @V{(f,(id)_i)}VV @VV{H(f)}V\\ (B_j)_{j\in J}@>>{\eta_B}> (1)_{j\in J}\end{CD}.$$

In particular, this means that an arrow $(f,(\alpha_i)_{i\in I}):(A_i)_{i\in I}\to (B_j)_{j\in J}$ is a trivial covering if and only if every arrow $A_i\to B_{f(i)}$ is an isomorphism.

On the other hand, given two families $(B_j)_{j\in J}$ and $(B_j)_{j\in J'}$, their coproduct is simply given by the family $(B_j)_{j\in J\sqcup J'}$, with the coproduct injections given by $(\iota_J,(id_{B_j})_{j\in J})$ and $(\iota_{J'},(id_{B_j})_{j\in J'})$. Thus an arrow $(f,(\alpha_i)_{i\in I}):(A_i)_{i\in I}\to (B_j)_{j\in J}$ is (isomorphic to) a coproduct injection if and only if $f$ is injective and every $A_i\to B_{f(i)}$ is an isomorphism.

These observations imply that if an arrow $\alpha:A\to B$ in $\mathsf{Fam}(\mathsf A)$ is such that $\Pi_0(\alpha)$ is a monomorphism, then it is a coproduct injection if and only if it is a trivial covering. Since the diagonal of $\alpha$ is split monomorphism, its image under $\Pi_0$ is one as well, and thus conditions 2a and 2b must be equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for this! I forgot that initial arrows also count as trivial covering morphisms.

Comment: How to see that being a trivial covering morphism implies separability using the unit-is-a-pullback and diagonal-is-a-trivial-covering definitions? Is it doable without cancellation properties and pullback stability?

Comment: @Arrow, Yes, you can prove this directly using the characterizations I give in my answer: if $(f,(\alpha_i)_{i\in I}):(A_i)_{i\in I}\to (B_j)_{j\in J}$ is a trivial covering, then its kernel pair is given by $(\pi_1,(\alpha_{i}^{-1})_{(i,i')\in I\times_J I}),(\pi_2,(\alpha_{i'}^{-1})_{(i,i')\in I\times_J I}):(B_{f(i)=f(i')})_{(i,i')\in I\times_J I}\to (A_{i})_{i\in I}$, so the diagonal is given by $(\delta, (\alpha_i)_{i\in I})$ (with $\delta:I\to I\times_J I$ the diagonal of $f$), so it is a coproduct injection.

Comment: That is the proof I saw. I guess left cancellation and pullback stability are the only option using the abstract definitions? (With respect to a general admissible adjunction, that is.)

Comment: For a general admissible adjunction, pullback-stability is pretty much the only thing you know about trivial coverings...

Comment: Is there a way to prove the image of $H$ contains the trivial coverings without also assuming the counit is an isomorphism?

Comment: Well, it should work as soon as $\eta_H$ is an isomorphism, or equivalently as soon as $H(\epsilon)$ is one...

Comment: Dear Arnaud, forgive me for reviving this thread. As you say, idempotence of $\Pi_0\dashv H$ is sufficient to conclude the image of $H$ is included in trivial coverings. On the other hand consider the prefactorization system generated by $\Pi_0\dashv H$ (i.e the one right-generated by the image of $H$). When the adjunction is simple the right class $(^\perp \operatorname{Im}H)^\perp$ can be shown to coincide with trivial coverings. Is it obvious that $\operatorname{Im}H\subset (^\perp \operatorname{Im}H)^\perp$? If so, this removes the need for idempotence hypothesis on $\Pi_0\dashv H$...

Comment: For any class $\mathcal{M}$ we always have $\mathcal{M}\subset (^\bot \mathcal{M})^\bot$, because (by definition) for any $m\in \mathcal{M}$ and $e\in (^\bot \mathcal{M})$ we have $e\downarrow m$.

Comment: Whoops, that was silly of me. But then, for any simple adjunction it should be easy to check the image of $H$ is contained in trivial coverings, yet I can only see this for idempotent adjunctions. I am able to explain my confusion?

Comment: Do you mean the image of $H$ or of $H^B$?

Comment: Of $H$. As you say $\operatorname{Im}H\subset (^\perp \operatorname{Im}H)^\perp$, so if the adjunction is simple (the right class consists of trivial coverings) I expected to easily see the naturality square of an arrow in the image of $H$ is a pullback (without assuming idempotence of the adjunction).